# Open Graph action Translation

Tags: facebook, translation, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to translate my Open Graph action from English to Japanese. I used "Translation admin panel" for translation and the status says "I approved", and it seems to be not translated. Anyone know how to publish translation? What does this "I approved " status mean?